# what kind of questions should i ask the user during the user interview to get insights for revamping website on-boarding?

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, interview, onboarding

this is my first week working in a startup as a ux strategist for the very first time. previously i've been working in an digital agency for 4 years. it's been hard to shift my mindset from a waterfall perspective to more agile perspective, especially my current work place's agile is not really mature yet. the product that we sell is a b2b saas product that provides supply chain management solution.

previously they didn't have any ux person yet. so they've put me in various teams to try to understand the business process and currently they put me under the on-boarding team. they're trying to revamp their on-boarding system during the trial period for the users.

i'm trying to do a user interview with our customers to get more feedback and insights about the product, especially for the on-boarding. it doesn't seem to be possible to do a user test for the current on-boarding at this stage. but i've been looking for ideas for the questions that i can ask to the user for this context.

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. If you can please narrow the question down. First define the aspects of on-boarding you're most concerned about and see if you can identify some potential-pain points.

Comment: @Mayo: my main concern about the current on-boarding system is they don't have a context for what process in the business we are trying solve in every feature. it is more just like a manual, like you click this, and then you click that, and done. while i personally think the on-boarding system should be able to highlight our product's 'wow' features that they really need.

Answer (score 2):

UX pros mistrust surveys since [survey answers are unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-report_study#Disadvantages). People tend to mis-remember things and provide answers that are not-quite accurate. (Not that people lie on surveys. We all tell certain stories about ourselves and those stories are never absolutely accurate.) The best way to learn about users is to observe them in the context where they'll be using your application.

But, if you can't observe, then interviews can work since they allow you to probe for specifics.

And if you can't do interviews, then surveys will have to do as a last resort. Avoid all "What features do you want?" questions. Instead, ask questions that reveal what people are trying to accomplish here and what the repetitive tasks are. Ask if people have ever done X and Y. I find that coming away with a list of the tasks people are trying to accomplish (and those they're not) and a list of their frustrations helps a great deal with designing a solution to support what users actually do.

You might want to avoid business-y terms like "onboarding" in your surveys. Keep everything in the user's language.

Comment: yes i don't think i should create the user test at this stage. i'm very new here and i want to learn more about all the issues that we have first, then start writing the user test plan. and yes, i agree that we shouldn't use surveys, because i can get broader answer by conducting user interview. but i'm not sure what kind of questions i should ask to get the right insights for me.